# Permalinks in Multisite not working

Tags: multisite, permalinks, htaccess

I'm using a subdomain multisite and I receive a 404 when trying to visit posts. The main domain works, but the permalinks aren't working. When I use the default permalinks, they work, but when I use the custom ones like this `/base/%category%/%postname%/` it's not working.

I'm wondering if it has to do with my .htaccess, since I've been editing that quite a bit.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?nofillers.com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?nofillers.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: What if you use the default `.htaccess` and go editing it bit by bit?

Answer (score 0):

For permalinks you may have to include index.php before the custom permalink structure within the permalinks settings option panel:

```
/index.php/%postname%/
```

Just a guess but thats what I had to do on a couple of my sites. Let me know if that does not work and then we can look at your .htaccess file.